# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Simple NSOutlineView DataSource with Structs, but not with Classes

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am making a simple `NSOutlineView` and am having trouble with crashes and apparent non-deterministic behavior. Here's the code for my view controller.

```
import Cocoa

struct Hierarchy {
    var name: String
    var children: [String]

    init(name: String, children: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
    }
}


class MainViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outlineView: NSOutlineView!
    var data: [Hierarchy] = [Hierarchy]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        self.outlineView.delegate = self
        self.outlineView.dataSource = self

        self.data = [
            Hierarchy(name: "Heading 1", children: ["Abc", "Def", "Ghi"]),
            Hierarchy(name: "Heading 2", children: [String]()),
            Hierarchy(name: "Heading 3", children: ["Jkl", "Mno", "Pqr"])
        ]
    }
}

extension MainViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        if let heierarchy = item as? Hierarchy {
            return heierarchy.children.count
        }

        return self.data.count
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        if let heierarchy = item as? Hierarchy {
            return heierarchy.children[index]
        }

        return self.data[index]
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        if let heierarchy = item as? Hierarchy {
            return heierarchy.children.count > 0
        }

        return false
    }
}

extension MainViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        var view: NSTableCellView?

        if let hierarchy = item as? Hierarchy {
            view = outlineView.make(withIdentifier: "AlphaCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
            if let textField = view?.textField {
                textField.stringValue = hierarchy.name
                textField.sizeToFit()
            }
        } else if let hierarchyChild = item as? String {
            view = outlineView.make(withIdentifier: "AlphaCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
            if let textField = view?.textField {
                textField.stringValue = hierarchyChild
                textField.sizeToFit()
            }
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

This will either show nothing in the Outline View, crash when trying to expand one of the headings, or open one of the headings to reveal "Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3" inside, nested.

HOWEVER. If I change from `struct`s to `class`es for `Hierarchy`, everything works. Why is this the case?

```
class Hierarchy {
    var name: String
    var children: [String]

    init(name: String, children: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
    }
}
```

Comment: Had exactly the same behaviour on El Capitan. Fixed by switching from a struct to class. It seems like it works on Sierra, though.

Comment: That Sierra/El Capitan difference is interesting. I'll have to try again now that I've updated. It's still confusing why this issue exists at all--my best guess is KVC or something else Objective C-related is to blame. \*shrug\*